# Prevent GRUB updates from changing EFI boot order

Tags: grub, ubuntu-18.04

I'm currently working on a tripple-boot system with Ubuntu 18.04, macOS and Windows. The standard bootloader that the firmware (ASUS Impact VII, APTIO-based EFI) is supposed to launch is Clover. Clover then runs GRUB 2, Apple's EFI bootloader or the Windows bootloader.

The problem is that when I update the grub-efi package on my Ubuntu 18.04 system via apt/dpkg, the EFI firmware will proceed to boot GRUB instead of Clover on the next reboot.

I understand that this happens because the GRUB setup changes the EFI variables to make itself the default bootloader. More specifically it does not pass `--no-nvram` to grub-install.

How can I make the GRUB EFI packages **not** modify the EFI boot variables via grub-install, so that Clover remains the default bootloader?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question: The postinst script of grub-efi-amd64 has the feature I asked for. It will pass `--no-nvram` to the grub-install binary when the debconf variable `grub2/update_nvram` is false.

Run `dpkg-reconfigure grub-efi-amd64` and answer "No" when prompted whether to maintain the nvram entries automatically.

Comment: A slightly longer version of this answer is available on a sister site https://askubuntu.com/a/1121143/25344

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in grub-efi-amd64-signed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1969845 so it's impossible to prevent this behavior without changing grub-efi-amd64-signed's postinst script manually.